# Microsoft Security Essentials quarantine location

Tags: windows-7, ms-security-essentials

Security Essentials has quarantined a file i need, it says it cannot restore it.

[image]

Where does Security Essentials store its quarantined files? I have searched and cannot find its location.

Windows 7 Pro 64bit.

Comment: [So where is the quarantine location?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/mse-protect_scanning/so-where-is-the-quarantine-location/66762822-9b8b-4585-9f52-0c12d169c193)

Comment: Should have been an answer not a comment.

Comment: I thought it was so trivial as a Google search that you might have deleted the question ;)

Comment: I did search, but did not find that link, now google will return this page as a better search result due to the specific title I used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows 7, the Microsoft Security Essentials quarantine location is :

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Quarantine\

Comment: The location you provided is for the wrong product.

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong product" ? It is for Microsoft Security Essentials

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like there is no file of any size in there to recover, it must have deleted it.

Comment: Microsoft AntiMalware is a different program...

Comment: Microsoft AntiMalware was its name before but the folder is definitely correct.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7, the Microsoft Security Essentials quarantine location is :

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Quarantine\
```

BUT the folder there only has a bunch of subfolder and files that are all **encrypted** and you can't open them via a text editor or even read any binary data.

So what you can do is to first **recreate the original folder** then you can restore it via the MSE app itself.

Use the command below if you want to fully recreate the folder and will **recursively** make the full path.

```
mkdir -p "D:\Folder\Folder2\Folder3\blah blah\"
```